# Windows 2003 HP SmartArray E200 password recovery

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-smart-array, password-recovery

I need to reset Windows 2003 administrator password on HP ML series server with E200 SmartArray.
Offline NT password recovery CD booted but could not find any disks.
I run driver autoload and lsmod shows cciss. So dmesg does. But no /dev/cciss/cXdY entries appears.

What can be done about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

For your immediate issue, using the *Offline NT password recovery* disk, please run the driver autoload several times. You're on a G5 ProLiant, and the utility needs to run the probe separately for each SCSI device driver. (e.g. you may have an Adaptec or LSI device that was probed first). There was a bug in the program that wasn't resolved until the [5/2011 release](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html).

If that fails, you have a number of password recovery options available. HP equipment is pretty standard and its [CCISS block device drivers](http://cciss.sourceforge.net/) are available in most rescue CD solutions.

My approach is to use the [PLD Rescue CD](http://rescuecd.pld-linux.org/) for this purpose. It's ~80 Megabytes and includes the `chntpw` *NT SAM password recovery* utility. I'm sure this could be substituted for any other modern Linux-based rescue disk, but this is part of my toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

You need a password recovery disk that supports mounting RAID volumes.  Try a different utility.  I'd recommend a Linux LiveCD based utility, [like Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).  As a disclaimer, I don't know that Ophcrack, specifically, will work, but a LiveCD should enable you to mount the RAID volume and then launch a password reset utility.